# Regex to extract images from HTML - how to get only JPGs?

Tags: php, regex, jpeg

I am using this PHP function to grab all `<img>` tags within any given HTML.

```
function extract_images($content)
{
    $img    = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($content),'<img>');
    $regex  = '~src="[^"]*"~';    

    preg_match_all($regex, $img, $all_images);

    return $all_images;
}
```

This works and returns ***all*** images (gif, png, jpg, etc).

Anyone know how to change the regex...

```
~src="[^"]*"~
```

in order to only get files with **JPG or JPEG** extension?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sooner or later the Regex Enforcement Agency will show up.  It might as well be me :)

The proper way to do this is with a proper HTML DOM parser.  Here's a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php) solution.  The usefulness of this is in that it's more robust than parsing the HTML by regex, and also gives you the ability to access or modify other HTML attributes on your `<img>` nodes at the same time.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

// To hold all your links...
$links = array();

// Get all images
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach($imgs as $img) {
  // Check the src attr of each img
  $src = "";
  $src = $img->getAttribute("src");
  if (preg_match("/\.jp[e]?g$/i", $src) {

    // Add it onto your $links array.
    $links[] = $src;
}
```

See other answers for the simple regex solution, or adapt from the regex inside my foreach loop.

Comment: @michael how does the saying go? "when you try to solve one problem with regex then you actually have 2 problems?" :) -- thx for your code, I'll see if I can implement it

Comment: @torr http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."

Comment: @michael - right on! - looks like your code works BUT I get thrown a bunch of errors like `Namespace prefix fb of attribute like:layout is not defined in Entity, line: 179` and `htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 349` -- I wonder if these are because of invalid markup. I am pulling in the HTML via `file_get_contents`. Do you think it would be bad practice here to suppress the errors using `@$dom->loadHTML($content)`?

Comment: @torr Try setting `$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;`.  Otherwise `simplexml_load_string()` might be more forgiving than DOMDocument?

Comment: @torr Otherwise, if you're not in control of both ends, it might not hurt to suppress warnings on it. (please no one downvote me for saying so!)

Comment: @michael - looks like `$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;` doesn't work (I still ge the error messages) - I think I'll stick to `@` unless there's a major reason not to use it here

Answer (score 2):

```
/src="[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg)"/i
```

i -> case insensitive match

Comment: You need to watch out here, in case someone uses a single quote around the value.

Comment: thanks @peter - for now I will be using the DOMDocument as below but your regex works fine